# Most likely path through a continuous time Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

If I have a discrete Markov chain, it's easy to find the most likely path through it: just look at the probabilities of following each possible path independently, and take the largest one.

In a continuous chain I am wondering if the same process works: that is, is the fastest path through a continuous time Markov chain just the most likely path through its respective embedded chain? Or, alternatively, could it be different?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What does "fastest" mean in this context?

Comment: Since there are rates on the continuous time markov chain, fastest means the path with the least mean expected transit time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the question is "What is the most likely path (sequence of states) of a continuous-time Markov chain (CTMC), given some evolution time $t$ and possibly intitial and/or final state?"

This problem has been solved [here](http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/9/77/3411.long) through a "Viterbi-like" dynamic programming algorithm. Matlab and R implementations are [available for download](http://www.perkinslab.ca/pubs/LLP2012.html) as well. While the paper talks about ion channels and HIV drug resistance, the results are applicable to any CTMC.